# What is "melodic modulation"?

Tags: theory, terminology, modulation

I've studied direct modulation and I understood it.
I've tried searching about "melodic modulation", but I couldn't find the meaning of it.

Could you please explain to me what "melodic modulation" is in music?

Comment: could it be that melodic is referring to *melodic minor* alternately to *harmonic minor*?

Comment: I think a little more context would help.  For example what motivated you to search for "melodic modulation"?

Comment: I've never heard of direct modulation or melodic modulation. I wonder if a dodgy website's involved.

Answer (score 1):

That’s what I’ve found about *Modulation in the melody*

*In many folk songs or chorales, modulation is already predetermined by the melody.*

and the this example:

[image]

(German wiki)

It shows how the melody is “modulating” from D to A-major and  B-minor using melodic segments and leading tones(by augmentation = sharp -> lead-tone).

Wiki e says:

**Melodic: recognizable segment of the scale of the quasi-tonic or strategically placed leading-tone**

Answer (score 0):

'Direct modulation' is a widely-used term for when you reach a cadence in one key then directly set off in a different one.  No pivot chord or modulatory passage.

As you have discovered from your lack of search results, 'Melodic modulation' is not a standard term.  So its definition is whatever you want it to be!   (Where did you encounter the term?  If in a textbook, THAT'S where you should look for the writer's definition of what he means by it.)

What MIGHT 'Melodic modulation' mean?   Well, obviously there's going to BE a melody, not just a chord sequence.  If you're playing in C major and start introducing F sharps, the melody could be said to be taking us on a melodic modulation into G major.   (Presumably the chords will follow.  Which might explain why describing 'Melodic modulation' as a separate thing doesn't happen much.)